# Using Jsp variable in servlet

Tags: jsp, servlets

servlet1

```
request.getSession().setAttribute("user", user.getUid());
request.getRequestDispatcher("home.jsp").forward(request,response);
```

home.Jsp code

```
<h5>Servlet communicated message to JSP: ${user}
     Please Select an image to upload</h5>   

<form action = "SaveInDBServlet" method = "GET"
         enctype = "multipart/form-data">
         <input type = "file" name = "filepath" size = "50" accept="image/*" />
         <br />
         <input type = "submit" value = "Submit" />

      </form>
```

user value is sent from servlet1 to JSP
and now I need to transfer it from JSP to servlet 2.
I need to access the value of the user in servlet 2
How to do this?

**$user is an attribute which was sent by servlet 1$user prints the value on this web page 
Now for further processing, this variable has to be sent to servlet2**

Comment: you have to pass it with either GET or POST request to servlet

Comment: Can you please provide a code snippet

Comment: you provide the code what you have tried to call the servlet from JSP

Comment: I have edited the code

Comment: @HeenaMittal add the code in servlet1 that add the user value

Comment: The code you shared ain't sufficient . Please add more and explain in detail

Comment: @user7294900 I have added the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all let me start with explaining with the overloaded `getSession()` methods. The no-arg `getSession()` always returns a new `session` object which is similar to `getSession(true)`, but in the case of `getSession(false)` it checks for an existing session, if present returns it or else returns null.

Once you have set an attribute to session, it will be available to a user until his session is available (not null) or not `invalidated`, so your data `user` will be available in your JSP and servlet2 also. But the method you are using to set attribute to the session is vulnerable, because `getSession()` can also return a new session in which your attribute won't be present.

So the safe way is to retrieve the session object to a reference, check whether it is null or not the get or set the attribute.

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
if(session != null) {
    //  set/get data whatever you need. Avoids NullPointerException
}
```

Second way is to use a hidden attribute in `JSP`, like this

```
<input type="hidden" name="user" value="<%=request.getAttribute("user") %>"/>
```

So you just need to set the attribute to request and get its value in `jsp` and set the value for hidden field. Now in the second servlet use the `getParameter` method (returns String) to get the value.

```
String user = request.getParameter("user");
```

Comment: using scriptlets is not encouraged,use JSTL instead.

Answer (score 1):

In your JSP do this

```
<form action = "SaveInDBServlet" method = "GET"
     enctype = "multipart/form-data">
     <input type = "file" name = "filepath" size = "50" accept="image/*" />
     <br />
     <input type = "hidden" name= "user" value="${user}"/>
     <input type = "submit" value = "Submit" />

</form>
```

In your servlet GET method

```
String username = request.getParameter("user");
```